# bootstrap-select for mobile and desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the [bootstrap-select plugin](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) with Bootstrap 4 framework and can't seem to figure out how I can get the plugin to display as is on desktop, but display the native browser wheel dropdown functionality on mobile devices.

Here is a code pen link https://codepen.io/dalondong/pen/GXrpBy

and this is the code the site says to use.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('mobile');
}
```

Comment: I have opened your code pen with my ASUS Zenphone 3 and it works. I see the Android native menu when I click on the dropdown.
You cannot symulate the behavior of the Android native menu with Device Mode in Chrome DevTools.